# How to handle Android to MySQL updates when smartphone is offline

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am currently working on a forum-like Android app which interacts with a MySQL database through JSON and PHP scripts. On certain occasions, the app has to send updates to the database, e.g. when a post to the forum is made or updated.

My question considers the situation that the smartphone is offline, i.e. doesn't have a internet connection thus cannot connect to the server, and tries to post something to the forum. However, due to the offline status, it cannot interact with the database immediately. In this situation we want to handle the messages in such a way that the post is sent to the database on the next instnce when the device connects to the internet.

What exactly has to be done on the app side to achieve that?

I guess the post has to be buffered in some directory locally and the app has to check the internet connection constantly. Does anybody know how to do that? Does JAVA provide certain functions for doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: store it into a cookie

Comment: or even don't allow the user to go into your app while he's notconnected to the internet until he's reconnected

Comment: You can use local storage like SQLite and synchronize with the server database when the device is connected to Internet

Comment: Can somebody tell me how exactly you store these commands in a cookie? Normally cookies are stored when you are online right? How can I store my own posts in a cookie and then send them when I am connected to the internet again?